# Question about taylor series$ -((2/x)/2!)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion, geometric-series

right now I'm learning about taylor series in uni and I'm getting kinda confused. 
The question is : 
find the polynomials of order $0,1,2,3$ generated by $f$ at $a$. 
$f(x) = 2 \ln (x)$, $a = 1$.
I can do out the question just fine, however when you get to the point of having $-((2/x^2)/2!)$ , why does this become $-(2/2!)$?

Comment: Check the terms in your question are correct - there shouldn't be any division by $x$ in a Taylor series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

Since $a=1$, we consider the function $$g (x)=f (x+1)=2\ln (x+1) $$

$$=2 (x-\frac {x^2}{2}+\frac {x^3}{3})+x^3\epsilon (x)$$

thus

$$f (x)=g (x-1)$$
$$=2(x-1)-(x-1)^2+\frac {2(x-1)^3}{3}+(x-1)^3\epsilon (x) $$

Comment: that would still become $1/(x+1)$ though right? so when you derive it again and put it over the $2!$ it would be $-(1/(x+1)^2)/2!$ right?